# jQuery list to start at 1, not 0

Tags: jquery, pagination, slideshow

I've read some previous questions about this but haven't found a solution.

I have a slideshow ck module installed on Joomla 3 which I modified it's CSS to show numbers instead of circles in the pagination.

The problem:

The module shows the pagination starting at number 0. I need it to start at number 1.

The question:

Is there a way to display the pagination as if 0 is 1, 1 is 2, 2 is 3, ect.?

The function is this one:

```
if($(pagination).length) {
        $(pagination).append('<ul class="camera_pag_ul" />');
        var li;
        for (li = 0; li < amountSlide; li++){
            $('.camera_pag_ul',wrap).append('<li class="pag_nav_'+li+'" style="position:relative; z-index:1002"><span><span>'+li+'</span></span></li>');
        }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no problem.

Comment: Just change the last span -> `<span>'+(li+1)+'</span>`

Comment: @Adam, I'm sorry if I didn't ask this the right way. In deed there wasn't a problem with the code itself. The problem was that my client needed the pagination to start at 1. I really needed a modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
if($(pagination).length) {
    $(pagination).append('<ul class="camera_pag_ul" />');
    var li;
    for (li = 0; li < amountSlide; li++){
        $('.camera_pag_ul',wrap).append('<li class="pag_nav_'+(li+1)+'" style="position:relative; z-index:1002"><span><span>'+(li+1)+'</span></span></li>');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Andres! You are also right. As @adeno commented, just changing li to (li+1) solved my problem.

Comment: welcome, you can also change your loop as follow: `for (li = 1; li <= amountSlide; li++)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using that "initialization" thing in the FOR() loop.

```
for([InitializeOnce]; [loopConditionBefore]; [loopActionAfter])
```

The following code means "start counting ***'li' at zero***, loop while li < amountSlide & increment li at the end of each loop"

```
for (li = 0; li < amountSlide; li++)
```

Your solution is intialize differently!  You want to start counting at 1 instead 0? Then initialize your counter - you guessed it - starting at 1!

```
for (li = 1; li < amountSlide; li++)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: This answer is also good Spanka. It makes the list start at number 1. But in my specific case, this approach helped with the pagination, but leaves one slide visible without its corresponding number in the pagination. Changing li to (li+1) did the trick as Andres and adeno suggested.

Comment: Ahh, that's because I forgot to change the loop condition!  Your question is really "how do count a 0 based array to make it 1 based for humans?" - the answer is offset loops. I gave you the iniitalize, but the wrong condition. Sorry!

If you initialize @ 0, your loop condition is **<**.  Start at 0, count to less than total items (3): 0-1-2.

If you initialize @ 1, your loop condition is **<=**.  Starting at 1, count to less than **or equal** to total items: 1-2-3

Counts, ranges, objects, collections, etc - this issue is constant. manual increments and such work, but can be error prone!